# CSS min() within calc() breaks in firefox, but not in chrome

Tags: css, firefox, min, css-calc

I want to calculate a certain width that is the full width of my window, minus 40px offset. Unless the window is bigger than the site's maximum width, 1600px. This works like a charm in chrome but breaks in firefox. Is there another way to achieve this?

```
width: calc(min(100vw, 1600px) - 40px)
```

Comment: use media query until there is more support for min()

Comment: So obvious, I guess I had one of these moments. Thanks!